# Alamofire cert pinning doesn't blocking requests

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ssl-certificate, alamofire

I've some trouble about SSL Pinning in Alamofire. I've examine all the document that I can found but I couldn't manage to handle it. I might get it wrong.

Currently, I am working on an example
https://github.com/antekarin/ios-ssl-pinning

I converted it to swift 3 and updated the pods to the latest version of Alamofire.

To make it clear; the project is use "github.com.cer" certificate, and because I define domain (like below) I expect to get success when I go to "https://github.com" and to get failure when I enter (in example) "https://twitter.com". But in every condition my request return some value and does not block other requests.

```
self.serverTrustPolicies = [
  "github.com": self.serverTrustPolicy!
]
```

Code:

```
    let githubCert = "github.com"
    let corruptedCert = "corrupted"

    var urlSession: Foundation.URLSession!
    var serverTrustPolicy: ServerTrustPolicy!
    var serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy]!
    var afManager: SessionManager!

    var isSimulatingCertificateCorruption = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.configureAlamoFireSSLPinning()
        self.configureURLSession()

        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    }

    // MARK: SSL Config

    func configureAlamoFireSSLPinning() {
        let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: githubCert, ofType: "cer")
        let localCertificate:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!

        self.serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
            certificates: [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)!],
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )

        self.serverTrustPolicies = [
            "github.com": self.serverTrustPolicy!
        ]

        self.afManager = SessionManager(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: self.serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }


    // MARK: Button actions

    @IBAction func alamoFireRequestHandler(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if let urlText = self.urlTextField.text {

            self.afManager.request(urlText).responseString { response in

                guard let data = response.data, response.error == nil else {
                    self.responseTextView.text = response.error.debugDescription
                    self.responseTextView.textColor = UIColor.red
                    return
                }

                self.responseTextView.text = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                self.responseTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thank for your comment. Did not know this.

Comment: Well.... presumably no-one thinks they can approach volunteers in real life and request that something is done to a particular timescale. Perhaps the problem with the internet is that the "culture of free" has become so ingrained that we forget other people are volunteers? Or do we just forget there are real people at the other end, with busy lives and deadlines of their own?

Comment: @halfer I still say thanks to you, about your opinion. But I think you overestimate about this. I don't want to mess my post with these comments and I don't have time for this. When I said "Did not know this", I mean I did not know that rule. For sure there are real people, and they can always decide to give their time to who they need or easily ignore them.

Comment: @GöktuğAral did you able solve the issue ?